# Is It Ok To Write "100%" In A Formal Text?

Tags: numbers

I'm writing a text that is neither mathematical, nor statistical, but rather I want to emphasize a point. For example, I'd say "It's 100% involuntary..."

Is it acceptable to employ "100%" in normal nonfiction writing, as a synonym for absolutely or completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statistical-sounding expression is no problem, but if you want to be *formal* in register, as your headline indicates, you should probably spell it out as “one hundred percent”—and also spell out “it is” (which latter you have here contracted).

Comment: Interesting, you've raised a point I hadn't considered. In formal text, I cannot use contractions?

Comment: Yes, @Timothy, you should edit them out at least if you want to achieve an academic level of formality (to which I customarily hold my university students).

Comment: Can you please recommend a particular reference work for learning about the formalities of academic writing?

Comment: @Timothy, there are lots of good English handbooks. I have my students buy [*The Little Seagull Handbook* from Norton](http://books.wwnorton.com/books/The-Little-Seagull-Handbook/), as most familiar to me. Above that level you get the official manuals of the various specific academic styles: MLA, APA, Chicago Manual. These are more expensive, less portable, and harder to use and learn from. Any college/university English handbook dated since about 2010 should be up to date with the latest editions of all three (MLA 3rd, APA 6th, CMS 16th); and second-hand pickings should be plentiful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a word instead of "100%" since the value is not meaningful...try ***"it's involuntary"*** or if emphasis is needed, ***"it's absolutely involuntary"*** or ***"it's entirely involuntary"***.

Comment: Or "altogether". (But don't call me Shirley.)

Comment: @TomZych, Airplane! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The type of writing you are doing also plays into your decision. For example, in legally binding documents, like contracts or exhibits to contracts, the spelled out number is the legally binding number. So if a text said that, "you are 99% (one-hundred percent) responsible", the 100% number would be legally binding, not 99%.